# Google maps marker event click issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

```
 function initMap() {
    var markers = [];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: { lat: -33.9, lng: 151.2 },
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false

    });

    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(null);

    @foreach (var item in Model.legs)
    {
        if (item.Lat != null && item.Long != null)
        {
            <text>

                var myLatLng = {lat: @item.Lat, lng: @item.Long};
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: '@(item.From) - @(item.To)',
                    icon: '@(Url.Content("~/content/images/Map-Marker.png"))',
                });
                marker.addListener('click', function() {
                    marker.setIcon('@(Url.Content("~/content/images/Map-Marker-Blue.png"))');
                    alert(' @item.Id clicked');
                });
                bounds.extend(myLatLng);
                markers.push(marker);                    
            </text>
        }
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

On google maps API I need to raise an ajax popup (not shown in the code) the alert item.id is in it's place.  On a marker click, the alert is correct in showing the id of the selected marker.  This part is fine.

I've added code to change the marker icon to a different icon when the marker is clicked, but this will change the icon of the last marker.  Regardless of which icon is clicked.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change marker color “onclick”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31196426/change-marker-color-onclick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this instead of marker , your marker will eventually point to the last marker because of scope chain

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
                this.setIcon('@(Url.Content("~/content/images/Map-Marker-Blue.png"))');
```

}

Hope it helps.